# How to get the OOB confusion matrix from `party::cforest()`?

Tags: r, random-forest, party

The `randomForest()` function in the `randomForest` package very helpfully [provides the confusion matrix based on out-of-bag prediction in classification](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomForest/docs/randomForest).

The `cforest()` function in the `party` package [does not seem to provide this information](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/party/docs/cforest). Searching for "confusion" in the [`party` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf) did not yield anything useful, nor did [searching here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+cforest+confusion). Maybe I'm overlooking something?

Is there a way to get the OOB confusion matrix for a `party::cforest()` classification model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took this from the party.pdf

compare, with OOB=TRUE and FALSE

```
set.seed(290875)
### honest (i.e., out-of-bag) cross-classification of
### true vs. predicted classes
data("mammoexp", package = "TH.data")
table(mammoexp$ME, predict(cforest(ME ~ ., data = mammoexp,
                                   control = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 50)),
                           OOB = TRUE))


                  Never Within a Year Over a Year
  Never           195            31           8
  Within a Year    57            46           1
  Over a Year      54            20           0

table(mammoexp$ME, predict(cforest(ME ~ ., data = mammoexp,
                                   control = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 50)),
                           OOB = FALSE))
  Never Within a Year Over a Year
  Never           212            22           0
  Within a Year    58            46           0
  Over a Year      54            17           3
```

Comment: I had hoped there might be something built-in, like for `randomForest`... ah well. Thank you!